# Notifying views of AppDelegate changes

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am developing an app (XCode 4 with storyboards, iOS5, single view app) that sends a URL request to an external server (thus leaving my app) and implements a custom URL scheme to handle the "response" from the external server.  The URL request and custom URL are working fine, but my question is about handling the incoming data.

My app is a single view controller that uses a Navigation controller at the top, with a table view controller as the first view.  From the first table view controller, there are a number of segues to other view controllers.

I implemented didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and openURL in my app delegate.  I need to send the data to my view controllers.  To do this I can use a singelton class, but how do I alert the views that the data has arrived?  I'm thinking that this alert code goes into applicationDidBecomeActive, but what method do I use to alert the other views?

--John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NSNotificationCenter](http://macdevelopertips.com/cocoa/basics-of-notifications.html).

Comment: Thanks Nathanial.  I looked at the link - it seems like that will do the trick!  So simple.....

Comment: To take it a step further, I can eliminate the singleton and pass an instance of incoming URL as the userInfo part of the notification.  Way cool!